# Cookie in GET REQUEST (REST) not in Cookies collection in response, but in header

Tags: c#, rest, cookies

Creating a rest request.  I can retrieve the cookie returned via the Set-Cookie header.  I am wondering why this would also not be included as part of the cookies collection in the response object.  It's no problem, I can parse the set-cookie header and create a Cookie object to use from it, but I am wondering what the reason it would not be in the Cookies collection.

Thoughts?

.NET 4.0, C#, Console App

```
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( "http://fakeurl/authenticate") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic someoooooobase64value==");

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
       string authCookieString = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
       //authCookieString.Split(
       Console.WriteLine(response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Response represent result coming from the server. Server may or may not re-set the same cookies.

As normal behavior for a server is actually **not** to set the same cookies again because it will simply consume bandwidth with no effect on browser's or consumer's behavior. The reason server will resend the same cookie if value need to change or expire.

Comment: Apparently I've read only title of your question "Cookie in GET REQUEST (REST)..." but did not read the rest carefully. No, I don't know answer to your actual question.